# Ros Mutiple Machine

Tags: ros, kinect, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I have to machine client and server.In client pc I have kinect, and I set the ROS_MASTER_URI = server ip.

When I run rviz in clien pc i got the image and pointclouds, but when i try to run rviz in master pc I can't get anything :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9915/ros-mutiple-machine/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-05-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks you I got it run well now, with you setting and disable firewall in both computer

```
sudo ufw disable
```

---

Originally posted by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) with karma: 121 on 2011-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my connectivity issues by playing with the 'rosnode' command. It lets you view and ping the other ros nodes that you may be connected to. In my case, I discovered that one of my nodes wasn't setup right so the connections would get blocked.

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to the ROS_MASTER_URI environment variable, you may also want to set ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP.

For example:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.21                                                     
export ROS_IP=192.168.0.21                                                           
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.21:11311
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-08**:
Might want to check that, it would be correct for the master computer settings, but not the client (ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME should be the client ip, not the master ip).

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-05-07**:
+1. Also, you might find this question and its answers useful: http://answers.ros.org/question/647/nodes-with-2-computers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problems occur when you have multiple network interfaces on your computers or hostnames are getting confused. To be safe I always set the triple on both master and client computers.

Master (192.168.1.100):

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.100
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.100
```

Client (192.168.1.101)

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.100:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.101
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.101
```

I also seem to have trouble with virtualbox nat, but bridged networking works fine. Other sources of information:

- [Ros Environment Variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME)
- [Ros Troubleshooting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Troubleshooting#Network_Configuration)

Also see patrick's link to a similar ros answer.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haresh Karnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33873/haresh-karnan/) on 2018-04-10**:
Thanks a lot. that solved my issue.

**Comment by [liver121888](https://answers.ros.org/users/68551/liver121888/) on 2021-01-23**:
Thank you. Your answer helps a lot!